# Android LinearLayout RelativeLayout Weight

Tags: android, layout

I'm trying to add an EditText and a Button on the same line and i would like to give 80% of the line to the editText and 20% to the Button.

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollViewChoosePlace"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_location"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:hint="location"
                android:inputType="text" />

            <!-- android:layout_alignParentTop="true" -->

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_find"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/et_location"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/et_location"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:text="find" />

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btn_find" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

and it doesn't work...

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Use a `LinearLayout` for weights. You can use a `weightSum` of 10 and give one view a weight of 8 and the other a weight of 2.

For your case:

```
<ScrollView...>
    <LinearLayout vertical>
        <LinearLayout horizontal weightSum=10>
            <EditText weight=8 />
            <Button weight=2 />
        </LinearLayout>
        <Fragment />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: It is also important to make all your child views have a height of `0dp` in order to truly have an 80-20% split.

Comment: Yeah that's true, in this case `width="0dp"` as it's a horizontal layout